# How can I load a fixed length (no delimiter) .DAT file to a SQL Server table using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-data-factory, data-transform

I have fixed length .DAT files in a ftp server and I need to bring them to ADLS using ADF in a .TXT format to be able to transform data in ADF before loading into a SQL Server table.

So far, I could copy the table as is in ADLS as a .DAT file. When I try to create a dataset in a text format in ADF it does not allow me copy the file without specifying the delimiter.

I need a solution where without any delimiter specified I am able to convert .DAT file to a .TXT file and store it in ADLS or be able to use the dataset without copying files to ADLS to transform dataset contents to do column mapping.

I would need to update the dataset daily because new file would be added everyday to the ftp server.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I tried the following:
Create a dataset in ADF by specifying "NO DELIMITER" and was able to preview data as shown [image: Dataset].This however does not allow me to copy dataset to ADLS because copy requires to define a delimiter.

Can I transform this dataset in the pipeline without copying to ADLS? Next step is to do mapping to load data from this dataset into a SQL Server table:[image: Column Mapping Example]

Answer (score 0):

> Create a dataset in ADF by specifying "NO DELIMITER" and was able to preview data. But this does not allow me to copy dataset to ADLS because copy requires to define a delimiter.

- ***When the column delimiter is defined as empty string, which means no delimiter, the whole line is taken as a single column.***
- ***Currently, column delimiter as empty string is only supported for mapping data flow but not Copy activity.***

So, if you are using copy activity with no delimiter you will get this error in validation as below.

[image]

To avoid this the work around is to use **`Data Flow activity`** to copy file with no delimiter from **source** to **sink**.

> I reproduced with **`No delimiter`** in dataflow.

- Dataset:
  [image]
- Dataflow using same file.
  [image]
- Pipeline running Successfully.
  [image]

Comment: So this will load data to a table with a single column?

Comment: Is there a way to use this file in ADF and do column mapping before loading in the target sql table in a similar manner as below: Store position 1-10 in column 1, position 11-15 in column 2, position 16-30 in column 3 and so on.

Comment: Yes you can use derived colum transformation and then for every column take a substring

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible for you to show me how similar to screenshots in your answer? I am fairly new in ADF and just beginning to start development.

Comment: Post your next ask as a New Qs so that it will help the community having the same issue and can answer that separately.